# Why does strcpy to a literal compile?

Tags: c, visual-studio, strcpy

In Visual Studio 2015, the following does compile:

```
strcpy("destination", "Source");
```

Shouldn't the compiler figure out that "destination" is a literal and cannot constitute a valid non-const char* parameter?

As a side note, it does "correctly" crash when it's run.

Comment: There is no warning?

Comment: There is definitely should be a warning about it.

Comment: I will need to re-test it, but no, I did not see any warning when I tested it monday

Comment: Have you tried raising the warning level?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: will do

Comment: The compiler doesn't know what strcpy does.

Comment: try using /Wall compiler flag, but like @JJF says, the compiler doesn't know that strcpy tries to write to the destination pointer.

Comment: @JJF Some compilers (for example GCC and Clang) manage to have checks for that. Visual Studio usually, it seems, lags behind those when it comes to give warnings for things like this.

Comment: I tried it in GCC, It gives a warning.

Comment: @denis I tried with gcc 5.3.0/cygwin, -Wall -Wextra -pedantic : no warning. That's tough.

Comment: Note that the program is not required to crash. The compiler is not required to issue a diagnostic.

Comment: I tried with gcc -Wall and didn't get any warnings either.

Comment: A compiler is not required to make string literals non-modifiable. Attempting to do so is UB so a compiler MAY allow this.

Comment: gcc, for example, had `-fwriteable-strings`. It was a bad idea for compiling bad code, and has been removed.

Comment: I should mention, the gcc flag changed the linking behaviour. With writeable strings, it put the string literals in a writeable section. This may or may not make a substantial difference, depending upon the target operating system.

Comment: @JJF Re "The compiler doesn't know what strcpy does": Mine does know exactly what strcpy does: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins

Comment: @JJF The compiler has a signature of `strcpy` which returns a non-const pointer to char.

Comment: in C, a reference to an array, like "destination", degrades to the address of the first byte of the array,  so the syntax is correct.  However, since literals are (normally) in a 'readonly' linker section, it (normally) will result in a 'seg fault event' when run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Context

Character string literals are and have always been non-const in C. The current standard draft n1570 says in 6.4.5/6:

> The multibyte character sequence [resulting from concatenation of adjacent string literals, -ps] is then used to initialize an **array of static storage duration** and length just sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, **the array elements have
>   type char** [and not const char, -ps].

The reason is, of course, that originally they *were* indeed usually writable. The program itself was writable; there was even self-modifying code. That is related because the string literals are produced and stored "together with the program" by the compiler.

It is modern memory management -- i.e., a matter of advanced machine architecture -- which makes it at all possible to generate a hardware exception when the program's memory is accessed. It is a matter of security to use that possibility. Not all architectures (can) do that, even today, and compilers may have options to control where strings go (e.g. `-fwritable-strings` with old gccs).

#### This Code

Grammatically the code is compliant, semantically it is UB per 6.4.5/7 in n1570: "If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
undefined."

Compilers could warn when addresses of string literals are assigned to non-const variables (or used to initialize non-const parameters in function calls), but the common ones I tried don't warn which puzzles me a bit -- a lot of implemented warnings seem less important and noisier.

#### strcpy()

As to the specifics of `strcpy()`: Some comments said that "the compiler doesn't know what `strcpy()` does". That is more often than not misleading:

- The standard library functions are well-defined by the standard. This knowledge could be used in the compiler. For example, tools like `lint` usually know about such semantics.
- The compiler and the default standard library are often developed in close cooperation and come as a bundle; because there is a great deal of interaction between compiler and library with regard to compiling the library itself, compiler bootstrapping etc. there is usually an exchange between both projects on a regular basis.
- Compilers are free to replace library functions with intrinsics, which would give them very intimate knowledge.

#### gcc

Indeed, [gcc happens to replace `strcpy`and many other functions with built-ins,](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins) so it *does have* first-hand information that the first address will be written to. It just does not use it.

Another gcc intrinsic is `printf()`, and here the compiler uses its knowledge of `printf`'s semantics to warn about format errors. That clearly demonstrates that a warning would be possible for `strcpy()` as well.

As an aside, gcc *does* warn about `"abc"[1] = 0;`. That is interesting because I had thought that the `strcpy()` intrinsic would be inlined (it must be short) so that with `-O3` and possibly `-flto` at some point the equivalent of `"destination"[i] = "Source"[i];` would actually be visible to the compiler and trigger that same warning.

#### Other Compilers

I tested VC 2013, gcc 5.3.0, gcc 4.7.2 and clang 3.7.1. None of them emits a warning for passing a string literal to `strcpy()`, but cremno pointed out that VC offers the `/analyze` option which catches the error.

Comment: VS has [`/analyze`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173498.aspx) though: `warning C6298: Argument '1': using a read-only string as a writable string argument.  This will attempt to write into static read-only memory and cause random crashes.`

Comment: Well, the program itself may or may not be writable, but that is none of the compiler's business. Somehow, I always tought that string litteral were defined as read only.

Comment: Good answer. VC documentation states this explicitly: **"String literals have type array of char (that is, char[ ])"** - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5x9d3a6(v=vs.140).aspx